# kotlin ktor sample not starting

Tags: kotlin, ktor

```
import io.ktor.application.call
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.response.respondText
import io.ktor.routing.get
import io.ktor.routing.routing
import io.ktor.server.engine.embeddedServer
import io.ktor.server.netty.Netty

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondText("Hello World!", ContentType.Text.Plain)
            }
            get("/demo") {
                call.respondText("HELLO WORLD!")
            }
        }
    }
    server.start(wait = true)
}
```

---

```
Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
Cause: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Error type encountered: [ERROR : For SuccessOrFailure] (ErrorType).
Cause: Error type encountered: [ERROR : For SuccessOrFailure] (ErrorType).
File being compiled at position: (12,22) in /Users/mac/Downloads/xoxoxo-server/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt
The root cause was thrown at: KotlinTypeMapper.java:114
File being compiled at position: file:///Users/mac/Downloads/xoxoxo-server/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt
```

Comment: Probably a bug.

Comment: What versions are you using of Kotlin and Ktor ?

Comment: Could you please provide the gradle/maven (whichever build tool you are using) configuration.